# css duplicated footer won't show icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the footer I was trying to copy: http://publish.gwinnett.k12.ga.us/gcps/home

Here is the jsfiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/r5gwdogq/

CSS I found: I wonder what's the stuff inside of { }

```
.gcps-icon-rss:before{content:"\e609"}
.gcps-icon-facebook:before{content:"\e60a"}
.gcps-icon-twitter:before{content:"\e60b"}
.gcps-icon-accessibility:before{content:"\e603"}.
```

I'm using their style sheet. Everything works great, just the icon won't show up, it shows rectangle instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]that's their own icon-font you could find the page requests it on 'network' tab of chrome's dev tools, you could try to get it by http://publish.gwinnett.k12.ga.us/ux/3/dist/fonts/gcps-icons.woff?-8wnfnr

how it works: 
your css defines font-family for .gcps-icon-rss etc. and attaches font that you should download

when you adds class .gcps-icon-rss to e.g. 'span' - your css puts the icon described as "\e609" before your span. you could create your own set on using awesome [icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app/) - you will find detailed readme after download

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to attach font files to jsfiddle, but I've updated the answer, maybe you'll find it helpful. you need to download font, put it to 'font' folder on the same level as your css.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go try it out

Comment: you're welcome :) that's really nice approach to add icons and icomoon app is really powerful and has a lot of free icons, so you can create your own light-weight and beautiful icons set

Answer (score 1):

The `content` property contains what should be put out into the `:before` pseudo element. In this case it's a unicode character.

The reason you're getting a black box is because the font that is used for the icons isn't being loaded.

As a proof on concept add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://publish.gwinnett.k12.ga.us/gcps/home/ux/3/dist/css/gcps-ux.css">
```

then the icons should load.

Please note that you shouldn't link off someone else's server, and also this may be a copyright violation in using their stylesheets without their express consent.

If you're looking for similar icons try [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

Comment: That's the stylesheet I add in my jsfiddle... It's still showing a box. I also tried to down the stylesheet and replace the .woff link. Would you mind to edit my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the font "GCPS Icons" from other website or you can use font awesome - http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/